# How to display word/excel documents in my Qt window using Linux and python?

Tags: python, linux, qt, openoffice.org

I am looking for the way to display word/excel documents in my Qt window using Linux and python but I couldn't find any.
Any suggestions are highly appreciable, thanks

Comment: i've googled it by phrases "pyqt openoffice display" but it didn't give me anything useful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My apporach would be to exploit Google Docs's [gdata-python](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/) APIs to read the arbitrary versions of Office documents and get documents as RTF for [QTextBrowser](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qtextbrowser.html) and as CSV for `QTable` Or perhaps even as HTML for both, depending on what functionality I would need.